# How to wait until mysql query is done and then continue to run the script?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I've made a class in which the constructor is being declared mostly by a mySQL query that looks like that:

```
constructor(username) {


        this.mysql = require('mysql');

// create a connection variable with the required details
        this.con = this.mysql.createConnection({
            host: "localhost", // ip address of server running mysql
            user: "root", // user name to your mysql database
            password: "", // corresponding password
            database: "db" // use the specified database
        });

        this.username = username;
        this._password = "";
        this.con.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", this.username, function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            this._password = result[0].password;
        });
    }

get password() {
        return this._password;
    }
```

The issue is , when I'm declaring the class like that:

```
const user= require("./user.js");
let bot = new user("user1");
console.log(user.password();
```

The code first accessing the get and getting undefined , and only after the the query is done.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a constructor asynchronous, that's not supported by Javascript.

What you can do is create an asynchronous `createUser` function that returns a user, and modify the constructor of your `User` class to take the data returned from the database.

Something like:

```js
class User {
    // Synchronous constructor
    constructor(mysqlData) {
        this._password = mysqlData.password;
    }
}

// Asynchronous create user function
function createUser(name, callback) {

    con.query('your query', [], function (err, result) {
        if (err) return callback(err); // Traditional error-first callback
        const user = new User(result[0]);
        callback(null, user);
    }
}

// Create the user and then do something once the user is created
createUser('user1', function (err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(user.password());
});
```

Unrelated tip: look into Promises and async/await, they are so much nicer to use than callbacks. Then your `createUser` function would look something like this (notice the `await` keyword instead of a callback for the query):

```js
async function createUser(name) {
    const result = await con.query('your query', []);
    const user = new User(result[0]);
    return user;
}
```

And then you can do `const user = await createUser('user1');` from another async function (you can only use `await` inside of an `async function`).

Keep in mind that for this to work, you need:

1. A runtime that supports async/await (Node 7.6+ or a modern browser), or Babel to transpile the code so it can run in older runtimes & browsers.
2. A mysql client that supports promises (there are wrappers on npm for most packages).

Comment: Thank you for you answer ! could you give an example of how that would look like with async/await please?

Comment: Sure! Added an example to my answer. PS. Don't forget to accept the answer if I've helped you solve your problem :)

Comment: Why is the result in the async query is different from the callback query? (the callback gives a good result with all the needed information and the async query gives some wierd data like _events:
   { error: [Function],
     packet: [Function],
     end: [Function],
     timeout: [Function],
     'start-tls': [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 5,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _callback: undefined,
  _callSite: Error)

Comment: For that you'll have to check out the docs of the promise wrapper, they'll probably have some examples of how to use it with await. I know with `mysql2/promise` you have to do `const [result] = await pool.query()`, because it returns multiple values so you use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the results out. Likely you'll have to do something similar for the library you're using, but it should be explained in the docs of that library.